# asp.net button not firing event

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

I have a case of an asp.net button not firing the event in code behind.

```
<asp:Button ID="butSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="butSubmitMata_Click" Text="Submit" />

protected void butSubmitMata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   labTester.Text = "Mata!!!";
}
```

The problem is I am using master pages  I cannot see the button in the design view so there is no way of creating the event by double clicking on it.

Is there any way to get this asp net button to fire the event

Comment: Where is this button placed in master page or content page ??

Comment: it is placed in the content page

Comment: Make sure you have place this code in code behind of your content page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check for page directive having AutoEventWireup attribute

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is in the content page, then open the content page in design view.

Comment: Because of the length or what?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling for two days trying to figure out why buttons are suddenly not posting back anymore. I found out it was because I had requireSSL `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>` set to true under web.config (which was fine on production server that utilizes HTTPS, but not on my development machine where I should had "false" (when using HTTP)